# Fedora 33: Installing Nvidia Drivers from Nvidia

Tags: fedora, boot, nvidia, display, gdm

I want to preface this by saying that I understand `RPM-Fusion` exists and that it has *a way* to install Nvidia drivers.

But, I am using Nvidia's cuda repo instead because I am interested in development *rather* than playing games (which is what my Windows computer on the remote controlled display switch is for).  Unfortunately, Windows is a very difficult platform for development compared to Unix-based OS's:

```
https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/fedora33/x86_64
```

From there, I have installed Nvidia's drivers (and Cuda drivers) via `yum` repo and `dnf`, but it appears as if Nvidia is not yet enabled. I trust Nvidia to deliver working Nvidia code, but it seems they missed something when it comes to working Linux packages -- that is fine.

But, there is some bit that needs to be set in some boot configuration somewhere to activate the installed Nvidia drivers.

This is getting back into the weeds and revisiting the manual installation process with grubby, gdm and Fedora (which is now obfuscated by the RPM-Fusion installation content).

---

The question is thus: what are the manual boot configuration settings that need to be adjusted to enable an installed Nvidia driver?  (I have already disabled, blacklisted and removed Nouveau)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit `/etc/sysconfig/grub` and append `rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau` to end of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=”…”`.

```
## Example row with Fedora 33 BTRFS ##
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rhgb quiet rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau"

## OR with LVM ##
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rd.lvm.lv=fedora/swap rd.lvm.lv=fedora/root rhgb quiet rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau"
```

Then update the grub2 conf

```
## BIOS ##
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg

## UEFI ##
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
```

Comment: I'll try this in a few hours thanks man